# Where am I screwing up

Tags: shell

I want to time in seconds for execution of shell script.

My implementation:

```
#!/bin/sh
START=$(date +%s)
echo $START
.
.
bla bla bla
.
.
.
END=$(date +%s)
echo $END
DIFF=($END - $START)
echo  "Time difference is "$DIFF
```

This is showing me END time and not difference.
I cannot guess the reason why minus is not working.

Comment: In case you don't know already, just use `time myprogram args..` to time your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using `bash`:

You need to use double parens to do arithmetic in the shell:

```
((DIFF = START - END))
#or
DIFF=$((START - END))
```

Note that you don't have to use dollar signs to read from variables inside of double parens.

Comment: You don't have to use the dollars; it doesn't hurt when you do.

Answer (score 1):

You need dollar double parentheses for arithmetic:

```
DIFF=$(($END - $START))
```

As in:

```
#!/bin/bash
START=$(date +%s)
echo $START
sleep 2
END=$(date +%s)
echo $END
DIFF=$(($END - $START))
echo  "Time difference is" $DIFF
```

[Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) Reference Manual says:

> #### 3.5.5 Arithmetic Expansion
>
> Arithmetic expansion allows the evaluation of an arithmetic expression and the substitution
>   of the result. The format for arithmetic expansion is:
>
> ```
> $(( expression ))
> ```
>
> The expression is treated as if it were within double quotes, but a double quote inside
>   the parentheses is not treated specially. All tokens in the expression undergo parameter expansion,
>   command substitution, and quote removal. Arithmetic expansions may be nested.

[See also](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs):

> #### 3.2.4.2 Conditional Constructs
>
> ((…))
>
> ```
> (( expression ))
> ```
>
> The arithmetic expression is evaluated according to the rules described below (see [Shell Arithmetic](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic)). If the value of the expression is non-zero, the return status is 0; otherwise the return status is 1. This is exactly equivalent to
>
> ```
> let "expression"
> ```
>
> See Bash Builtins, for a full description of the let builtin.